# Add the items from one list to another list in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two arraylists say

```
ArrayList<BaseItem> normal;
ArrayList<BaseItem> highlighted;

normal = new ArrayList<BaseItem>();
highlighted = new ArrayList<BaseItem>();
```

what I am doing is I am Iterating through a 3rd list(called MyItems) and adding the items in it called highlight and normal to the above two lists like this.

```
  for (Iterator<BaseItem> iterator = MyItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        BaseItem itemtype = iterator.next();
        if (itemtype.isHighlight()) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);

        }
        else{
            normal.add(itemtype);

        }

    }
```

So my question is I want to add every 5th and 6th item of the highlited list to the list called normal .i.e elements like 5,6,11,12,17,18 and so on

and also I want to add every 6th and 7th item of normal list to highlighted list i.e 6,7,13,14 and so on.

so now my highlighted and normal lists will contain the items like this

```
 Highlighted -> highlighted1,highlighted2,highlighted3,highlighted4,normal6,normal7 highlighted7,highlighted8.highlighted9,highlighted10,normal13,normal14 and so on

 Normal ->  Noraml1,normal2,normal3,normal4,normal5,highlighted5,highlighted6,normal7,normal8,normal9,normal10,normal11,normal12,highlighted11,highlighted12 and so on
```

Any help is always appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, use a counter when after 5 and 6 insert in your list, add in normal list instead of highlighted list

Try this:

```
int highAdded = 0;
int normalAdded = 0;
for (Iterator<BaseItem> iterator = MyItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    BaseItem itemtype = iterator.next();
    if (itemtype.isHighlight()) {
        highAdded++;
        if (highAdded == 5) {
            normal.add(itemtype);
        } else if (highAdded == 6) {
            normal.add(itemtype);
            highAdded = 0;
        } else {
           highlighted.add(itemtype);
        }
    }
    else{
        normalAdded++;
        if (normalAdded == 6) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);
        } else if (normalAdded == 7) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);
            normalAdded = 0;
        } else {
           normal.add(itemtype);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I write this code:

```
public class StackOverFlowSample {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> lstHigh = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lstNormal = new ArrayList<String>();

        lst.add("highlighted01");
        lst.add("highlighted02");
        lst.add("highlighted03");
        lst.add("highlighted04");
        lst.add("highlighted05");
        lst.add("highlighted06");
        lst.add("highlighted07");
        lst.add("highlighted08");
        lst.add("highlighted09");
        lst.add("highlighted10");
        lst.add("highlighted11");
        lst.add("highlighted12");
        lst.add("highlighted13");
        lst.add("highlighted14");
        lst.add("highlighted15");
        lst.add("highlighted16");

        lst.add("normal01");
        lst.add("normal02");
        lst.add("normal03");
        lst.add("normal04");
        lst.add("normal05");
        lst.add("normal06");
        lst.add("normal07");
        lst.add("normal08");
        lst.add("normal09");
        lst.add("normal10");
        lst.add("normal11");
        lst.add("normal12");
        lst.add("normal13");
        lst.add("normal14");
        lst.add("normal15");
        lst.add("normal16");

        int highAdded = 0;
        int normalAdded = 0;
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = lst.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String itemtype = iterator.next();
            if (itemtype.startsWith("highlighted")) {
                highAdded++;
                if (highAdded == 5) {
                    lstNormal.add(itemtype);
                } else if (highAdded == 6) {
                    lstNormal.add(itemtype);
                    highAdded = 0;
                } else {
                   lstHigh.add(itemtype);
                }
            }
            else{
                normalAdded++;
                if (normalAdded == 6) {
                    lstHigh.add(itemtype);
                } else if (normalAdded == 7) {
                    lstHigh.add(itemtype);
                    normalAdded = 0;
                } else {
                   lstNormal.add(itemtype);
                }
            }
        } 

        String result = "HIGHLIGHTED ARRAY: ";
        for (String curr : lstHigh) {
            result += curr + ", ";
        }
        System.out.print(result);

        result = "NORMAL ARRAY: ";
        for (String curr : lstNormal) {
            result += curr + ", ";
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
HIGHLIGHTED ARRAY: highlighted01, highlighted02, highlighted03, highlighted04, highlighted07, highlighted08, highlighted09, highlighted10, highlighted13, highlighted14, highlighted15, highlighted16, normal06, normal07, normal13, normal14,

NORMAL ARRAY: highlighted05, highlighted06, highlighted11, highlighted12, normal01, normal02, normal03, normal04, normal05, normal08, normal09, normal10, normal11, normal12, normal15, normal16,
```

Tell me if it's OK ;)

Comment: ,Thanks a lot,+1 for the help ,but its not working in a right way.

Comment: @Raghav: If you write what difference I try to fix to aim your expected behaviour

Comment: I am not getting the items in an expected sequence.in case of highlighted list after first 4 items 5th and 6th place/item should be replaced by normal items(normal6 and normal 7) and in case of normal the 6th and 7th place/items has to replaced by highlighted items. this should continue for both the lists.just have a look at my updated question.At the bottom i have updated the expected sequence for both the lists.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Raghav: Dear, I read again my code, there was an error (in normalAdded cicle, I put highAdded = 0), now I fix it. Try now, I think it's OK.

Comment: Thanks Joe,I will try it now.but have u added the modified code here ?

Comment: @Raghav: here: else if (normalAdded == 7) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);
            highAdded = 0;
        } 
        
        becomes 
        
        else if (normalAdded == 7) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);
            normalAdded = 0;
        }

Comment: ok,thanks but my doubt is the arrays length and items is not fixed,i will get the 100 no of items in to each list from the server.

Comment: I dont want to add the items manually, so will  the modified code will work for this scenario?

Comment: @Raghav: Dear, I write a simple example, you can replace my manual filling with your object (change the type in iterator too). The code works indipendently by its size. The only constraints are position about highlighted and normal element to switch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort Joe,but one final question is i m expecting this sequence actally.  Highlighted -> highlighted1,highlighted2,highlighted3,highlighted4,normal6,normal7 highlighted7,highlighted8.highlighted9,highlighted10,normal13,normal14 and so on

 Normal ->  Noraml1,normal2,normal3,normal4,normal5,highlighted5,highlighted6,normal7,normal8,normal9,normal10,normal11,normal12,highlighted11,highlighted12 and so on

Comment: I mean in case of highlighted after highlighted 4,u can see normal 6 and normal 7, and also in case of normal after normal 5 its highlighted 6 and highlighted7 and so on,how can we achieve this sequence?,Actually this is the only/main objective of my question.Thanks

Comment: Ok, you muyst use add with two parameters: add(index, element); Later I try to fix

Comment: ,Thanks, i will wait for your help.

Comment: Hi,any help on this??Thanks